# Grunt exec clear pub folder

Tags: magento2, grunt

When i use `grunt exec:theme` it clears all files in pub/static but does not copy new images, scripts and fonts.

I dont have any errors in CLI. 
I clear all cache and i use grunt refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Try last command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

i follow these steps:

grunt exec:theme
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
grunt less:theme
grunt watch:theme